# JavaFX Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, javafx

I am not using maven, gradle or something like that.

I can running program on intellij idea but when i build artifacts and i runned the executable jar file from command prompt with `java -jar myProgram.jar` i  am getting this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class myProgram.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myProgram.Main
```

But when i try the program from command prompt in src folder with `javac -classpath . myProgram/Main.java` i am getting this error:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
                         ^
myProgram\Main.java:4: error: package javafx.fxml does not exist
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
                  ^
myProgram\Main.java:5: error: package javafx.scene does not exist
import javafx.scene.Parent;
                   ^
myProgram\Main.java:6: error: package javafx.scene does not exist
import javafx.scene.Scene;
                   ^
myProgram\Main.java:7: error: package javafx.stage does not exist
import javafx.stage.Stage;
                   ^
myProgram\Main.java:8: error: package javafx.stage does not exist
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
                   ^
myProgram\Main.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
public class Main extends Application {
                          ^
  symbol: class Application
myProgram\Main.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
                      ^
  symbol:   class Stage
  location: class Main
myProgram\Main.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
    public static void setWindowForMainPage(Stage stage, URL page) throws IOException {
                                            ^
  symbol:   class Stage
  location: class Main
myProgram\Main.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
    public static void setWindowForLoginPage(Stage stage, URL page) throws IOException {
                                             ^
  symbol:   class Stage
  location: class Main
myProgram\Main.java:19: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
myProgram\Main.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
        loginPage = getClass().getResource("pages/loginPage.fxml");
                    ^
  symbol:   method getClass()
  location: class Main
myProgram\Main.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
        mainPage = getClass().getResource("pages/mainPage.fxml");
                   ^
  symbol:   method getClass()
  location: class Main
myProgram\Main.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
        Parent mainPage = FXMLLoader.load(page);
        ^
  symbol:   class Parent
  location: class Main
myProgram\Main.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
        Parent mainPage = FXMLLoader.load(page);
                          ^
  symbol:   variable FXMLLoader
  location: class Main
myProgram\Main.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
        stage.setScene(new Scene(mainPage, 1093, 730));
                           ^
  symbol:   class Scene
  location: class Main
myProgram\Main.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
        Parent loginPage = FXMLLoader.load(page);
        ^
  symbol:   class Parent
  location: class Main
myProgram\Main.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
        Parent loginPage = FXMLLoader.load(page);
                           ^
  symbol:   variable FXMLLoader
  location: class Main
myProgram\Main.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
        stage.setScene(new Scene(loginPage, 400, 170));
                           ^
  symbol:   class Scene
  location: class Main
myProgram\Main.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
                        ^
  symbol:   variable StageStyle
  location: class Main
myProgram\Main.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
        launch(args);
        ^
  symbol:   method launch(String[])
  location: class Main
21 errors
```

[my file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xzv8Y.png)

In normally, i am using JDK 16 & JavaFX 16. I can run my other builded jars. But only this project gives this error. And i also tried it with JDK 14 & JavaFX 14.

My vm options:
`--module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-14.0.2\lib" --add-modules javafx.fxml,javafx.controls,javafx.base,javafx.web,javafx.media,javafx.graphics  --add-opens javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.runtime=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=ALL-UNNAMED`

My libraries:

font-awesome
html-unit
jasper-reports
java-fx
jfoenix

Comment: if i use jdk 8 will my problem solved? I tried run this project in other computers. And they don't work.

Comment: Yes try JDK 8, as it still had JavaFX together with the JDK